# Error en query parametrizada: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: mysql, python, python-2.7, sql, tkinter

Estoy desarrollando una GUI que maneja mi base de datos en Python 2.7 que se conecta a una base de datos MySQL. Ya puede insertar, consultar y borrar pero lo que aun no puede hacer es actualizar con la sentencia UPDATE. Me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1541, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\efrias002\Desktop\Python\SQL Tkinter v2.py", line 136, in 
cambiar
cursor.execute("UPDATE base17 SET %s='Erick' WHERE ID =%s",[d2][d1])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Por que arroja ese error?. Mi codigo es este:

```
def win2 ():
  t1 = Toplevel(bg="Brown")
  t1.title("Modificar Datos")
  t1.geometry('580x400')
  t1.focus_set()
  t1.grab_set()
  t1.transient(master=ventana)
  t1.resizable(width = FALSE, height = FALSE)


  lb1 = Label(t1,text='ID del Registro',bg="Cyan2")
  lb1.grid(row=5, column=1,padx=70,pady=10)

  inf2=StringVar()
  t2=Entry(t1,textvariable=inf2)
  t2.grid(row=6,column=1,pady=15)

  lb2 = Label(t1,text='Campo del Dato a Modificar',bg="Cyan2")
  lb2.grid(row=5, column=3,padx=25,pady=5)

  inf3=StringVar()
  t3=Entry(t1,textvariable=inf3)
  t3.grid(row=6,column=3,pady=15)

  lb3 = Label(t1,text='Dato a Modificar',bg="Cyan2")
  lb3.grid(row=11, column=2,padx=10,pady=10)

  inf4=StringVar()
  t4=Entry(t1,textvariable=inf4)
  t4.grid(row=12,column=2,pady=10)

  def cambiar():
     d1= inf2.get()
     d2= inf3.get()
     d3= inf4.get()
     conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "unitec", db = "efrias002")
     cursor = conn.cursor()
     cursor.execute("UPDATE base17 SET %s='Erick' WHERE ID =%s",[d2][d1])
     conn.commit()
     conn.close()

     tkMessageBox.showinfo("Info","Registro Modificado")



  wb = Frame(t1, width = 15, height = 10)
  b1 = Button(wb, text = "Cerrar(X)", bg = "SkyBlue", command = t1.destroy)
  b1.pack()
  wb.grid(column = 1, row = 13, pady=85)

  wc = Frame(t1, width = 15, height = 10)
  b2 = Button(wc, text = "Enviar", bg = "Orange", command = cambiar)
  b2.pack()
  wc.grid(column = 2, row = 13, pady=35)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EL problema como muestra el error está en:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE base17 SET %s='Erick' WHERE ID =%s",[d2][d1])
```

en concreto al pasar los parámetros de la query parametrizada, `[d2][d1]`. Las variables `d1` y `d2` haacen referencia ambas a cadenas que provienen de sendas `tkinter.StringVar`, cuando haces `[d2]` creas una lista que contiene la cadena asociada a la variable `d2`:

> ```
> >>> d2 = "Hola"
> >>> [d2]
> ['Hola']
> ```

Por lo que `[d2][d1]` se interpreta como un intento de indexado sobre a lista `[d2]` usando como índice la variable `d1`, la cual es una cadena, y por tanto no es un índice válido.

> ```
> >>> ["hola"]["mundo"]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
> ```

Debes pasar simplemente **una sola tupla (o lista)** con los parámetros de la query a substituir:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE base17 SET %s='Erick' WHERE ID =%s", (d2, d1))
```

> **Nota:**: si se usa una tupla y solo hay un parámetro hay que recordar siempre agregar una coma después del mismo, en caso contrario los paréntesis no indicaran una tupla y tendremos un error como consecuencia. En vez de:
>
> ```
> cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = %d', (13))
> ```
>
> debe ser:
>
> ```
> cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = %d', (13,))
> ```